# Заменить часть большого XML файла

Tags: c#, xml

Есть большой XML файл в котором нужно поменять элемент с определенным именем и все дочерние элементы на элемент. Использовать `XDocument.Load()` невозможно, так как выходит `SystemOutOfMemoryException`. Для примера конструкцию вида:

```
<e>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</e>
```

Заменить на `<elem>val1</elem>` учитывая вложенность.

Comment: Это конечно оффтоп, но я уже не первый вопрос от Вас вижу, который, по сути, сводится к одному и тому же. Может Вы не тот инструмент используете? На мой взгляд, все Ваши проблемы решаются с помощью XSLT и не надо никакого C#.

Comment: Возможно Вы правы

Comment: @e1s: А вы что-то уже пытались сделать, чтобы реализовать требуемую функциональность?

Comment: @e1s какой у вас размер документа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразование одного XML в другой лучше делать при помощи XSLT, как и сказал @ixSci. Но, согласно ответу в этом [посте](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bb5a473-98c4-4f77-ad08-cf3e1dfd60e9/reducing-memory-usage-with-xslcompiledtransform?forum=xmlandnetfx), проблемы с потреблением памяти всё равно будут:

> XSLT id defiled as a transformation over cached (in memory) data and as a result has problems with scaling documents up.

Поэтому будем читать документ при помощи `XmlReader`, писать при помощи `XmlWriter`, находя все вхождения нужного элемента (`<e>`) и заменяя его (на `<elem>val1</elem>`). Код парсинга XML взят [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx) и немного доработан, чтобы не потерять атрибуты и обработать пустые элементы. Возможно, понадобится обработать другие типы XML-узлов, например, чтобы не потерять комментарии. Пример нужной вам обработки будет выглядеть так:

```
private static void ProcessXml(XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (reader.Name == "e")
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("elem");
                    writer.WriteString("val1");
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    continue;
                }

                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.Name, reader.NamespaceURI);
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Исходный XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <f>
    <e>
      <c/>
      <d/>
    </e>
  </f>
  <e>
    <a/>
    <b/>
  </e>
</root>
```

Результат:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <f>
    <elem>val1</elem>
  </f>
  <elem>val1</elem>
</root>
```

Comment: Можно использовать другой процессор XSLT, вовсе необязательно использовать встроенный от MS.

Answer (score 3):

Решение на основе XmlDocument / XPath / XSLT будет загружать весь документ в память. И занимать при этом примерно в 5 раз больше памяти, чем документ на диске. XSLT 3.0 включает в себя поддержку streaming-а, но [стандартные классы C# его не поддерживают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net).

Если

- время обработки некритично.
- и рабочее решение с XDocument / XSLT уже есть.
- и размер документа сопоставим с достумным объемом памяти (оперативной + места на достаточно быстром диске) - т.е. весит он порядка гигабайт, а не терабайт.

то самый простой способ - это переключиться на x64. Там приложению будет доступно 4 терабайта памяти (при нехватке оперативной - будет свопить).

- выбрать активной платформу x64 или AnyCPU на тулбаре или в Build / Configuration Manager.
- снять чекбокс Prefer 32 bit в свойствах проекта.
- при необходимости - выставить [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects].(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) в конфиге.
- заранее увеличить объем своп файла минимум до размера входного xml * 5.

Скрестить пальцы и запустить приложение.

P.S. простой != более технически совершенный.