# Исключение out of memory c# winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Вывожу xml в datagridview таким кодом:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
MessageBox.Show("Загружено");
```

Максимально что получается загружать это файл 240 mb в котором 135 000 строк и 18 столбцов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как загружать бОльшие файлы?

Памяти в этом компе 4 гига. Для него это максимум. Перед парсингом закрываю все программы

Comment: использовать sax парсер или, как рекомендуют java'сты - докупить планку памяти.

Comment: Кто и как планирует работать потом с 135к строк в табличке? Визуально как то работать собрались или что делаете такое?

Comment: _"как загружать бОльшие файлы?"_ -- вам именно в DataSet? падает при вызове dataSet.ReadXml или при выводе в dataGridView?

Comment: Мне это все нужно чтобы просто посмотреть на экране что есть в xml. Понажимать на заголовки столбцов типа посортировать. Если есть какой-то другой метод, то Dataset не принципиально. лишь бы работало. Просто на просторах инета нашел самое просто это dataset. 135 000 строк без пагинации, просто списком

Comment: @Stack Честно не знаю что выдает ошибку. Обновил вопрос. Добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: @Андрей _"не знаю что выдает ошибку."_ -- внизу button1_Click, а дальше ReadXml. понятно

Comment: @Андрей если вместо `dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");` вызвать `XElement.Load("file.xml");` тоже падает?

Comment: @Stack Заменил как предложили только 1 строку, файл как бы прогружается без проблем, только в datagrid ничего не выводится и счетчик говорит что загружено строк 0, столбцов 1

Comment: @Андрей _"прогружается без проблем"_ - хорошо. значит xml без оибок. а проблема в dataSet.ReadXml. _"в datagrid ничего не выводится"_ -- чтобы выводилось надо привязывать XElement к datagridview, но это отдельная тема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OutOfMemoryException вызываетя не нехваткой физической памяти, а нехваткой виртуальной памяти в 32-х битном процессе. Ее доступно всего около 2Gb на процесс, и чуть больше 1.5Gb для кода из-за накладных расходов.

Т.е. если у вас 64-х битная система, то вам скорее всего поможет [просто переключение приложения на 64-бита](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435957/177221):

- выбрать активной платформу x64 или AnyCPU на тулбаре или в Build / Configuration Manager. При отсутствии - создать новую конфигурацию в Configuration Manager.
- снять чекбокс Prefer 32 bit в свойствах проекта.
- при необходимости - выставить [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) в app.config.

  ```
  <configuration>
    <runtime>
      <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
  </configuration>
  ```
- заранее увеличить объем своп файла минимум до размера входного xml * 5.

Это уберет технический лимит в полтора-два гигабайта (реальный лимит в 300-400 из-за особенностей организации DataSet), в который вы упираетесь. Т.е. это позволит вам загружать сколь угодно большие файлы. Но при нехватке памяти система начнет свопить.

---

Если при этом вы получите слишком активный своп на диск при подгрузке файлов - пересматривайте подход к подгрузке данных. DataSet занимает в памяти в несколько раз больше, чем XML на диске.

Смена типа с DataSet на XElement просто даст вам чуть меньше накладных расходов, и тем самым немного поднимет порог размера файла, но незначительно. Т.е. она позволит вам загружать "чуть бОльшие файлы", а не бОльшие в общем смысле.

Мининимальные накладные расходы будут при использовании обычной строгой типизации:

- Объявите собственный класс, с полями соответствующими отображаемым колонкам.
- Используйте XmlReader для подгрузки XML и вручную создавайте по экземпляру своего класса на каждую строку. экземпляры складывайте в список.
- Список выставьте в качестве DataSource у грида.

Comment: Не могу найти "выбрать активной платформу x64 или AnyCPU на тулбаре или в Build / Configuration Manager" - у меня русская версия

Comment: @Андрей у вас на тулбаре все равно должнен быть выпадающий список с надписью Debug. ищите в нем :)

Comment: Да, про файл подкачки я забыл. Он у меня 500 мег, сделал 5 гигов и сразу загрузил XML 500 мегов почти на 300 000 записей. Правда ждал почти 6 минут ) Секундомером засекал на файле 180 мегов разницы в скорости загрузки x64 x86 и Any - у меня нет

Comment: _"DataSource занимает в памяти в несколько раз больше, чем XML ... Смена типа с DataSource на XElement"_ -- `DataSet`, а не DataSource

Comment: @Stack спасибо, исправил